# Twitter Streaming - Find Top 10 trending topics | PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Am doing a project to find top 10 trending topics or hashtags on Twitter. Am creating a class with the code below:

```
class TweetsListener(StreamListener):
  def __init__(self, csocket):
      self.client_socket = csocket
  def on_data(self, data):
      try:
          msg = json.loads( data )
          print(msg['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8'))
          return True
      except BaseException as e:
          print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
      return True
  def on_error(self, status):
      print(status)
      return True
```

Below is the code for sending data:

```
def sendData(c_socket):
  auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
  twitter_stream = Stream(auth, TweetsListener(c_socket))
  twitter_stream.filter(track=['india']
```

Here `twitter_stream.filter` is filtering messages with tag India. I want to get all the messages from Twitter. In short, I do not want a filter to be applied. Is there a way to do the same?

Any help appreciated.
 - P.S : Novice in Spark streaming and PySpark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter now offers a sample stream: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/overview/GET_statuse_sample.html

It's fairly new so I'm not sure if the wrappers (looks like you're using Tweepy) have implemented it yet, but it shouldn't be hard to interface with.